# Why (+) is concatinating in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
var total_quantity = parseInt(0);
var total_price = parseFloat(0);
$('#ticket_list').each(function () {
    total_quantity += parseInt($(this).find('li .ticket_quantity option:selected').text());
    total_price += parseFloat($(this).find('li .ticket_price').attr('data-val'));
});
console.log(total_quantity, total_price);
```

When the tickets quantity is `3` and `4` it gives `34`.
Why?? What am I doing wrong?
The same in ticket price

My html code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="ticket_list">
<li class="ticket_box">
    <div class="pull-right" style="width:70px">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select
                class="form-control ticket_quantity"
                id=""
                name="count_1"
                onchange="theEvent.calcTickets();">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:calc(100% - 100px)">
        <h4 class="ticket_name">free1</h4>
        <span class="ticket_price" data-val="0">БЕСПЛАТНЫЙ</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
<li class="ticket_box">
    <div class="pull-right" style="width:70px">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select
                class="form-control ticket_quantity"
                id=""
                name="count_2"
                onchange="theEvent.calcTickets();">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:calc(100% - 100px)">
        <h4 class="ticket_name">Общий доступ 10</h4>
        <span class="ticket_price" data-val="11">11 сомони</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: `parseInt(0)` ===> `0`

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet?

Comment: Concatenation occurs when your inputs are strings.

Comment: @PranavCBalan I don't use stacksnippet

Comment: Can you use typeOf and confirm what is the return type you are getting for parseInt? Just in case parseInt is overridden somewhere.

Comment: @Nitheesh Parsing to Int or Float is not working on string vals?

Comment: @Nitheesh typeof of total_quantity and  total_price is number and number

Comment: @ShuhratjonJumaev Please reproduce this issue in a snippet. So that looking into this will be easy.

Comment: @ShuhratjonJumaev please define your variable like `var total_quantity = 0;`

Comment: `+` concatenates when it encounters strings so it should be garden variety debugging either with `console.log(typeof x)` or in the debugger to see where you are getting a string that you aren't aware of.  Seriously, you should not need our help for this.  Do some basic debugging yourself.  Also, we can't do that debugging for you because you did not provide a runnable snippet of code.  This should take about 2 minutes for you to debug yourself.  If you don't know how to use the debugger, this is an excellent time to learn.

Comment: can you post your HTML code?

Comment: Also, `parseInt()` is for converting strings to numbers, so there's NO reason to use `parseInt(0)`.  That is just wrong and unnecessary.

Comment: @MayankVadiya define variable like var total_quantity = 0; not worked

Comment: Which browser are you using? :)

Comment: @AnuragSinha google chrome and it's updated

Comment: @SanjayPatel posted my html

Comment: in which function your javascript code is called?

Comment: @SanjayPatel jsfidlle http://jsfiddle.net/YJG79/144/

Comment: @PranavCBalan can u c my jsfiddle example ?  http://jsfiddle.net/YJG79/144/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the wrong thing with your `each` function.

Instead of 
`$('#ticket_list').each(...`

you should be using 
`$('#ticket_list li').each(...`

and then remove the `li` from the internal `find`s.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding , you have given same class name for both select box is 'ticket_quantity',i think you have to set 'ticket_price' name to second select box.